# NSFetchedResultsController, refetch data with external condition

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` to get the data for an `UITableView`. During the creation of the `NSFetchedResultsController` I create a `NSPredicate` that filters the data with an external condition. What's the proper way to refetch the data? Just nil'ing the my `__fetchedResultsController` and recreating it seems a little bit brutal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in my comment above I figured it out. What you need to do is save a reference to the `NSFetchRequest` and manipulate that straight away when needed. As a second step, you need to tell your `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch it's data again.

I did this by adding two new methods to the default `NSFetchedResultsController` "stack":

```
- (void)configureFetchRequest {  
    NSObject *myExternalDependency = …;

    if (!__fetchRequest) {
        __fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    }

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [__fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"someValue == %@", [myExternalDependency someProperty]];
    [__fetchRequest setPredicate:filter];
}

- (void)performFetch {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

So what I basically do now is call these two methods on creation of `__fetchedResultsController` (which I do initialize using `__fetchRequest`, of course) and every time my external dependency changes. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The `initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:` documentation states:

> **Important:** You must not modify fetchRequest after invoking this
>   method. For example, you must not change its predicate or the sort
>   orderings.

So you have to recreate the FRC (and call `reloadData` on the table view) when the predicate changes.

**EDIT:**

The same "NSFetchedResultsController Class References" also states [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW34):

> **Modifying the Fetch Request**
>
> You cannot simply change the fetch request
>   to modify the results. If you want to change the fetch request, you
>   must:
>
> 1. If you are using a cache, delete it (using deleteCacheWithName:).
>      Typically you should not use a cache if you are changing the fetch
>      request.
> 2. Change the fetch request.
> 3. Invoke performFetch:.

So my first answer above is probably wrong. If I understand it correctly:

- You cannot modify the fetch request assigned to the FRC.
- But you can build a *new* fetch request (with a new predicate) and assign that to the FRC (`controller.fetchRequest = newFetchRequest`) if you follow the three steps above.

This means that you don't have to recreate the FRC itself.

(I hope that I got it right now :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! And sorry for not reading the documentation properly. ;) I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @flohei: Gern' geschehen :-) It was useful for me as well to get this sorted out as the documentation *seems* to contradict itself.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work since the `fetchRequest` property is readonly. What does work, though, is saving the reference to the `fetchRequest` and manipulating this later on without trying to assign a new one to the `fetchedResultsController`.

Comment: But thank's for the hint anyway. That pointed me to the right direction. :)